# How to sort the date and stored in local variable in c#

Tags: c#

```
List<DateTime> evtFileDate = new List<DateTime>();    
evtFileDate.Add(eventFile.EventFileDate);
```

I added date to list, How to sort the date and stored in local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will sort the contents of the `evtFileDate` in place:

```
evtFileDate.Sort();
```

And if you wanted to preserve the order in the original list but instead have a new list which is sorted you could do this:

```
List<DateTime> sortedList = new List<DateTime>(evtFileDate);
sortedList.Sort();
// At this stage evtFileDate list remains unsorted while sortedList 
// will contain the sorted values
```

Comment: Thank u very much... How to store the sorting values in local variable or DateTime

Comment: The `evtFileDate` list is sorted in place. So after calling the Sort method on it, the elements will already be sorted. Or maybe you want to have a new list which is sorted, without modifying the original one?